# Find area with most points in a 2D plot

Tags: geometry, optimization, combinatorial-geometry

Assume I have got a set of points; their locations are scattered around a 2D plane. Like:

```
p0 = x0, y0
p1 = x1, y1
p2 = x2, y2
...
pn = xn, yn
```

*We will be given a box of size `p*q`, and we will have to find a region where the number of points is maximized.*

Any particular way to solve this problem? I'm trying to get steps, not an actual solution. Thanks.

Similarly, how to do this for a 3D dataset?

Comment: You have $n+1$ points and width $n$?

Comment: Also, must the box have sides parallel to the axes?

Comment: Please answer the first question by @RobPratt : are you sure you want the width of the box to be equal to the number of points minus $1$ ? It looks strange ? Isn't it a typo ?

Comment: That was a typo... I've fixed it... sorry about that...